# Different results for auto.arima with d=1 in R version 3.2.0 and R version 3.2.2

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have the R version 3.2.0 in one computer and the version 3.2.2 in another and the same version of the package "forecast" (6.1) in both of them. When I apply the `auto.arima` function with `d=1` to the vector `fec1` (data below) in the computer with version 3.2.0, it gives me an ARIMA(1,1,1). In the computer with version 3.2.2, it gives me an ARIMA(1,1,0) with drift instead. Why does such a difference happens? When I omit the option `d=1`, I get the same result in both computers.

```
fec1 <- c(9.53408021, 9.48993631, 9.44261613, 9.38585482, 9.31611858, 
          9.24743801, 9.19483663, 9.11690414, 9.05586032, 8.96781034, 
          8.85437896, 8.73956021, 8.62587246, 8.49758284, 8.41877774, 
          8.29737132, 8.02294327, 7.62604834, 7.32936532, 7.10006394, 
          6.87039464, 6.56332757, 6.27195705, 5.97089310, 5.69537808, 
          5.46074967, 5.19061116, 4.90749261, 4.61822473, 4.39635507, 
          3.96883450, 3.71230296, 3.43604354, 3.15150833, 2.82864081, 
          2.51857560, 2.27264470, 2.06785600, 1.86116599, 1.61452534, 
          1.41214847, 1.26673153, 1.15033592, 1.00646045, 0.83493055, 
          0.65399085, 0.47450499, 0.30408840, 0.18216540, 0.09006937, 
          0.00000000)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [PR#16278](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16278), "nested arima model has higher log-likelihood", which as noted in the [change log for 3.2.1](https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/NEWS), affects arima calculations with d >= 1:

> arima(*, xreg = .) (for d >= 1) computes estimated variances
>         based on a the number of effective observations as in R version
>         3.0.1 and earlier.  (PR#16278)